# Как перевести каждый кадр видео в 8 битную цветовую палитру (256 цветов)?

Tags: python, numpy, видео, обработка-изображений

На выходе я ожидаю некое  подобие GIF'a, а получаю ч/б изображение

Нерабочий код для видео (выдает ч/б):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/777/Desktop/test.mp4')
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', np.array(frame.quantize(colors=256, method=2)))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Рабочий код для отдельных изображений:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('C:/Users/777/Desktop/test_1.png')
result = image.quantize(colors=256, method=2)
result.save('C:/Users/777/Desktop/test_2.png')
```

Оригинал

[image: Оригинал]

Изображение на выходе

[image: Изображение на выходе]

Как перевести каждый кадр видео в 8 битную цветовую палитру (256 цветов)?

Цветовая палитра едина для всех и каждый кадр не может иметь свою цветовую палитру. Если нужного цвета в палитре нет, то цвет округляется до ближайшего похожего.

Comment: Проблема с видео в том, что один кадр может быть в синих тонах и вы сделаете палитру 256 синих оттенков, а второй кадр бордовый, а в палитре ни одного похожего цвета .. Как вы планируете это решать? (это повлияет на то каким будет правильный ответ на ваш вопрос)

Comment: В PIL есть у изображения `mode`: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes. В `Image.fromarray` вроде бы он -- один из параметров, может, Вам нужно попробовать передавать этот `mode` туда (а именно, `P`, как я понимаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял - вы хотите получить кадры в градациях серого (8 бит):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

fn = r"D:\download\Time - 6200.mp4"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fn)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame', grey)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```